# A java application can have how many thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I know it is very basic question to ask, but really do not know too much. 
Is it possible to have more than one thread pool in a single java application.

Second when Singleton instance is created, can it be shared with application too. As I know about Once Singleton instance is created then they are accessible globally. What does mean exactly globally here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243422/is-having-a-single-threadpool-better-design-than-multiple-threadpools is related

Answer (score 1):

Basically - as many as you need and no more.

You will need one thread pool for each process that requires its own pool.

For `Process` I mean *mechanism that requires a differently configured pool*. For example, if you are servicing network requests and managing some long calculations then you would use two different pools as the calculations would use the threads in a completely different pattern that the network requests pool would be used.