# Single vs Multiple ExecutorServices

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have to query a bunch of endpoints. Every endpoint has a bunch of queries that should be executed in different intervals. I'm trying to decide whether to use a single ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor or assign separate ExecutorServices to every endpoint. Here's how I see the tradeoff.

**Single ExecutorService:** I want to per endpoint use up at most 1 thread from pool to not starve other endpoints(query can block with a timeout), hence I'd have to in a `period = gcd of all intervals` run a task that for every query checks if it was ran in its interval and if it wasn't running it.

**Separate ExecutorServices:** I can make a periodic task for every query instead of timing it on my own. Stopping multiple pools within a time limit becomes messier however since in the first approach tasks can run multiple queries I would probably have to implement some sort of a custom shutdown there to avoid big shutdown times.

The second approach seems better to me. However, I'm not sure whether creating this many thread pools causes any problems that I don't know of. What do you think?

Comment: A key problem here is the use of sync remote calls. Can't this be done async? Having many thread pools, (e.g. one per endpoint) could lead to problems due to a lack of control on the number of created threads.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26243422/217324

Answer (score 0):

**like this you can create multiple thread pool**

```java
public class ThreadPool {

    private static ExecutorService shopifyExecutor = null;
    private static ExecutorService[] pools = null;
    private static final int NUM_PROCESSING_QUEUES = 10;

    public static synchronized ExecutorService getShopifyThreadPool() {
        if (shopifyExecutor == null) {
            shopifyExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_PROCESSING_QUEUES);
        }
        return shopifyExecutor;
    }

    public static synchronized ExecutorService getShopifyThreadPool(int id) {
        if (pools == null) {
            pools = new ExecutorService[NUM_PROCESSING_QUEUES];
            for (int i = 0; i < pools.length; i++) {
                pools[i] = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            }
        }
        ExecutorService service = d > 0 ? pools[id % NUM_PROCESSING_QUEUES] : pools[0];

        return service;
    }
}
```