# Is it better to use different Executors (one for each class) or share one between different classes?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, completable-future

I have to create some fully async classes with the `CompletableFuture`. For example:

```java
public class A {
    public CompletableFuture<String> methodA() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  {
            // ...
            return "123";
        }, // Executors );
    }
}

public class B {
    public CompletableFuture<String> methodB() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->  {
            // ...
            return "ABC";
        }, // Executors);
    }
}
```

According with the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) the `supplyAsync` runs the supplier in a `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` but is not what i really want. I need to manage the `Executors`

Is it better to use two separate `Executors` (one for class `A` and one for class `B`) or create one externally and pass the same in the two classes?

Comment: This seems similar to  https://stackoverflow.com/q/26243422/217324

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that the use of multiple `Executors` might affect performance.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all that you have two different classes. What _might_ matter is what kind of tasks you intend to submit to the executor or executors. E.g., one reason for having two executors is if you expect one of them to work its way through a backlog of big tasks, and you want the other one to be available to perform short, high-priority tasks.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your example.